# empty sites-enabled folder vagrant homestead (laravel 5.2)

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

when I goto my host i.e. "ao.dev:8000" ,***this site can't be reached,ao.dev refused to connect*** is displayed.

my homestead.yaml file:

[image]

console showing empty sites-enabled folder:

[image]

[image]

VirtualBox Manager:

[image]

hosts file:

[image]